# Getting Exception When Invoking The Subroutine ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

I have SQL Server Compact 3.5 database that contains account information. But everytime I call the function ExecuteReader I get this exception below:

> The column name is not valid. [ Node
>   name (if any) = ,Column name = ID ]

But that is the correct column name. The column names are the following: Username, Password, Date Created, and etc.

Here is the code below:

```
            SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Databinding Login Form\Databinding Login Form\MyDatabase#1.sdf; Password=*********");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ID=Username", connection);
            SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (username.Text == reader["Username"] as string && password.Text == reader["Password"] as string)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access Denied 5", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a column called "ID"?

It looks like you are asking for all accounts which have the same value in "Username" and "ID" columns? Did you meant to substitute "ID" for something?

Example

```
Where Username = 'EnteredUsername'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ID=Username" may be the problem. As you mentioned Username is a column-name; looks like you should be putting the user id in the query i.e "dlopez" for instance: "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ID='dlopez'"

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause is cause the error.  I assume you want to select only one Account where the ID is equal to a local variable caller `username`.  One solution is:

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ID='"
  + username + "'", connection);
```

A more correct solution is to use a SqlCeParameter:

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ID=@UserName", connection);
SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.Value = username;
com.Parameters.Add(param);
```